# I want to install a Blender add-on using a Python file but I always get a error message

Tags: python, blender, add-on

I don't use blender so much and today is the first time I'm using a Python file, so I'm having trouble with it. I want to install a add-on but I need to use a Python file, okay then, I installed Python and made the file but when I try to install the add-on in Blender, this error message appears:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7uXp.png)

So I tried a lot of forums but none helped me, I hope you guys can help.

Here is the code of the Python file:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/08965641f2fe3825c480eb7faacf9fb6/raw/429fed6ff0670e2612feca8e9d537c1b9dfe4b62/rbxblender.py

Thank you, and sorry for the writing errors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python but it would probably be useful if you can copy the relevant code referred to in the error message and add it to your question. Thanks

Comment: From the error message it would appear the file you're trying to load contains python version string instead of the code (moreover, said version string belongs to python2 - blender have used python3 for a long time). Open the file in text editor and make sure it contains the same code as in your link, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The line in the error message looks like the start of a python terminal, so there is something wrong in the steps you are doing. You don't need to install or run a different version of python, blender includes the python interpreter in it's install.

What you need to do is -

1. Save the file you that is available in the gist link you provide.
2. In blender's preferences click Install addon from file and choose the file you just saved.
3. The addon will then be shown so you can enable it.

You will find [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) to be a better place for blender help.